# Why is `invokespecial` used to invoke `<init>` method in java?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, constructor, jvm

Why is `invokespecial` used to invoke `<init>` method in java?

I read at multiple places but could not understand the perfect reason?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is why not `invokestatic`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These link are useful with very simple language

http://arhipov.blogspot.in/2011/01/java-bytecode-fundamentals.html

http://commons.apache.org/bcel/manual.html

This article from ibm is also nice with good example

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibm/library/it-haggar_bytecode/

Answer (score 4):

From [here](https://www.vmth.ucdavis.edu/incoming/Jasmin/ref--33.html):

> The main use of `invokespecial` is to invoke an object's instance initialization method, `<init>`, during the construction phase for a new object.

Also from [here](http://zeroturnaround.com/labs/java-bytecode-fundamentals-using-objects-and-calling-methods/):

> In other words, `invokespecial` is used to call methods without concern for dynamic binding, in order to invoke the particular class’ version of a method.

Second quotation is **the most applicable** to your question cause we know that calling constructor (`<init>`) method has always static binding.